# Send generated PDF with DomPdf as attachment with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, dompdf

I have been able to use dompdf to stream output but how can I make it send via email

```
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$image = "../img/logo2.png";
$html = '<h1>Hello World</h1>' ;

$dompdf->load_html($html);

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();
$domdpf->stream();
```

how can I make it send via PHPMailer
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your last line to $pdf = $dompdf->output();

Then you can use the addStringAttachment function in PHPMailer (https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addStringAttachment)